# Referential transparency with polymorphism in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, referential-transparency, higher-rank-types

Say I have a function:

```
f :: Int -> (Rational, Integer)
f b = ((toRational b)+1,(toInteger b)+1)
```

I want to abstract away the (+1) like so:

```
f :: Int -> (Rational, Integer)
f b = (h (toRational b)
      ,h (toInteger b))
    where h = (+1)
```

This wont work obviously, but if I specify the type signature it will work:

```
f :: Int -> (Rational, Integer)
f b = (h (toRational b)
      ,h (toInteger b))
    where h :: Num a => a -> a
          h = (+1)
```

Say I now want to further abstract the function by passing h as a parameter:

```
f :: Num a => Int -> (a -> a) -> (Rational, Integer)
f b g = (h (toRational b)
        ,h (toInteger b))
    where h :: Num a => a -> a
          h = g
```

I get an error that the inner a is not the same a as the outer one.

Does anyone know how to write this function correctly?
I want to pass a polymorphic function `g` to `f` and use it polymorphically.

I have encountered this situation multiple times now in very different projects, and I could not find a good solution.

Comment: Welcome to the world of *higher ranked types*!

Comment: "This wont work obviously" Actually, it's not obvious that this won't work: `(+1)` is polymorphic, only the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) prevents `h` from inheriting this trait. If you set `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, your second code box works fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution: using the forall quantifier like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
f :: Int -> (forall a. Num a=> a -> a) -> (Rational, Integer)
f b g = (h (toRational b)
        ,h (toInteger b))
    where h :: Num a => a -> a
          h = g
```

Which of course can be turned into:

```
f :: Int -> (forall a. Num a=>a -> a) -> (Rational, Integer)
f b g = (g (toRational b)
        ,g (toInteger b))
```

Comment: This is exactly right. Without the forall Haskell will try to specialize the function argument within the function body. This leads to the unsolvable system `(Rational ~ a) && (Integer ~ a)`. The forall binding says that you're going to pass in an unspecialized function and specialize it only at the call site. The downside is that you can't pass another `a` type in and be sure it matches the function—not that you would do that in this situation.