# When are type signatures necessary in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

Many introductory texts will tell you that in Haskell type signatures are "almost always" optional. Can anybody quantify the "almost" part?

As far as I can tell, the *only* time you need an explicit signature is to disambiguate type classes. (The canonical example being `read . show`.) Are there other cases I haven't thought of, or is this it?

(I'm aware that if you go beyond Haskell 2010 there are plenty for exceptions. For example, GHC will never infer rank-N types. But rank-N types are a language extension, not part of the official standard [yet].)

Comment: Are you asking for a big list, or just examples?

Comment: How about [this instance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27019906/839246)?  The compiler inferred different types on each side of the tuple for the same expression because of how it was being used.  It's not immediately obvious why, but with a type signature all of a sudden everything makes sense.  Granted, this is still to disambiguate typeclasses.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Monomorphism restriction

If you have `MonomorphismRestriction` enabled, then sometimes you will need to add a type signature to get the most general type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonomorphismRestriction #-}
-- myPrint :: Show a => a -> IO ()
myPrint = print
main = do
  myPrint ()
  myPrint "hello"
```

This will fail because `myPrint` is monomorphic.  You would need to uncomment the type signature to make it work, or disable `MonomorphismRestriction`.

#### Phantom constraints

When you put a polymorphic value with a constraint into a tuple, the tuple itself becomes polymorphic and has the same constraint:

```
myValue :: Read a => a
myValue = read "0"

myTuple :: Read a => (a, String)
myTuple = (myValue, "hello")
```

We know that the constraint affects the first part of the tuple but does *not* affect the second part.  The type system doesn't know that, unfortunately, and will complain if you try to do this:

```
myString = snd myTuple
```

Even though intuitively one would expect `myString` to be just a `String`, the type checker *needs* to specialize the type variable `a` and figure out whether the constraint is actually satisfied.  In order to make this expression work, one would need to annotate the type of either `snd` or `myTuple`:

```
myString = snd (myTuple :: ((), String))
```

Comment: The second one surprised me. But I suppose it's kind of like the canonical `show []` needing a concrete type even though it (probably) doesn't matter.

Comment: It's similar but not quite the same: in the case of `show []`, the compiler cannot decidably tell whether a list is empty: imagine something like: `show resultFromAComplicatedFunction`.  In the case of tuples, the compiler could (in theory) tell.

Comment: What about `myTuple' :: (Read a, Show a) => (a, String); myTuple' = let x = read "0" in (x, show x))`? It has a type analogous to your original `myTuple` type, but its `snd` still obviously depends on the choice of `a`.

Comment: You're right, I guess it's not as obvious to the compiler as it might seem.

Answer (score 25):

Polymorphic recursion needs type annotations, in general.

```
f :: (a -> a) -> (a -> b) -> Int -> a -> b
f f1 g n x = 
    if n == (0 :: Int)
    then g x
    else f f1 (\z h -> g (h z)) (n-1) x f1
```

(Credit: Patrick Cousot)

Note how the recursive call looks badly typed (!): it calls itself with *five* arguments, despite `f` having only *four*! Then remember that `b` can be instantiated with `c -> d`, which causes an extra argument to appear.

The above contrived example computes

```
f f1 g n x = g (f1 (f1 (f1 ... (f1 x))))
```

where `f1` is applied `n` times. Of course, there is a much simpler way to write an equivalent program.

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, as I'm sure you know, types are *inferred*. In other words, the compiler works out what type you want.

However, in Haskell, there are also polymorphic typeclasses, with functions that act in different ways depending on the return type. Here's an example of the Monad class, though I haven't defined everything:

```
class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    fail :: String -> m a
```

We're given a lot of functions with just type signatures. Our job is to make instance declarations for different types that can be treated as Monads, like `Maybe t` or `[t]`.

Have a look at this code - it won't work in the way we might expect:

```
return 7
```

That's a function from the Monad class, but because there's more than one Monad, we have to specify what return value/type we want, or it automatically becomes an IO Monad. So:

```
return 7 :: Maybe Int
-- Will return...
Just 7

return 6 :: [Int]
-- Will return...
[6]
```

This is because `[t]` and `Maybe` have both been defined in the Monad type class.

Here's another example, this time from the random typeclass. This code throws an error:

```
random (mkStdGen 100)
```

Because `random` returns something in the `Random` class, we'll have to define what type we want to return, with a `StdGen` object tupelo with whatever value we want:

```
random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Int, StdGen)
-- Returns...
(-3650871090684229393,693699796 2103410263)

random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Bool, StdGen)
-- Returns...
(True,4041414 40692)
```

This can all be found at [learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) online, though you'll have to do some long reading. This, I'm pretty much 100% certain, it the only time when types are necessary.

Comment: This is correct, but "disambiguating typeclasses" is exactly what the question *doesn't* ask for.

Comment: This is true, but I need to explain the only instance for other people visiting this question.