# Haskell type inference priority?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

As far as I know, haskell infers *the most general possible type*, being

```
integers      = [1,2,3]
integersOrNot = [1,2,3]

routine :: IO ()
routine = do
   let x = map (\i -> i / 2) integersOrNot
   return ()
```

When I test type of `integersOrNot`, I get

```
*Main> :t integersOrNot
integers_ :: [Double]
```

Given

```
*Main> :t 1
1 :: Num a => a
```

Haskell didn't have much options. But how come

```
*Main> :t integers
integers :: [Integer]
```

not `integers :: (Num a) => [a]`? Does that mean `Integer` is a "default" real type for `Num` kind?

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/MonomorphismRestriction. BTW, Haskell doesn't really “infer types in a lazy manner”, rather it always infers _the most general possible_ type.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, only if there is a most general type. I seem to recall that there are some weird cases where it infers something less general even when there is a most general type, but I may be confused or that may only be true with certain GHC extensions.

Comment: @dfeuer: yeah, it won't infer a more general rank-N type, but it will give the most general rank-1 type (provided you turn off the monomorphism restriction).

Comment: @dfeuer There are some cases where inference fails shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067905/when-are-type-signatures-necessary-in-haskell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.haskell.org/MonomorphismRestriction

as suggested by @leftaroundabout